# Same Time Request Decrement

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

**SOLVED**
Concurency / Atomic Update use following operator $inc or $set

How to prevent request like this?

I have a code on rest api (express.js) that works as a balance deduction when a user purchases a product, but I found a bug that the user made 3 requests on different devices.

**User Collection:**

| UserID | Balance |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10.000 |

**Cart Collection:**

| CartID | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 8.000 |
| 2 | 7.000 |
| 3 | 5.000 |
| 4 | 3.000 |

**Transaction Collection:**

| TransactionID | CartID | UserID | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | SUCCESS |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | SUCCESS |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | SUCCESS |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | SUCCESS |

**Result User Balance:**
I don't know why the result can be negative, while the code has been checked that if the balance is insufficient then the user cannot make a purchase

| UserID | Balance |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | -13.000 |

Then how to handle this?

[image: created_at]

```
// JSON BODY
const body = req.body

// FROM middleware
const userId = req.userAuth

// GET user by ID
const user = await Module.User.findById(userId)

// GET Cart
const Cart = await Model.Cart.findOne({
    _id: req.params.id,
    user_id: user.id,
    status: 'UNPAID'
})

// CHECK IF USER HAS ENOUGHT BALANCE or POIN
if (body.payment_method === 'BALANCE' && user.balance < Cart.product.price) {
    return res.status(422).json({ message: 'Not Enough Balance' })
} else if (body.payment_method === 'POIN' && user.poin < Cart.product.price) {
    return res.status(422).json({ message: 'Not Enough Poin' })
}

// CHECK FOR DECREMENT (BALANCE or POIN)
if (body.payment_method === 'BALANCE') {
    user.balance_before = user.balance
    user.balance_after = user.balance - Cart.product.price
    user.balance = user.balance_after
} else if (body.payment_method === 'POIN') {
    user.poin_before = user.poin
    user.poin_after = user.poin - Cart.product.price
    user.poin = user.poin_after
}

// DECREMENT SAVE
await user.save()
```

Comment: Can you share your current code, sample dataset and expected outcome?

Comment: @ray updated, i don't know how to prevent this thank you

Comment: Likely a [transaction API](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/#transactions-api) is needed for your case. You will need to wrap your code logic into a single transaction.

Comment: @ray isn't it the same if the user makes a request at the same time? even less than a second which I don't understand, because in this case the user can login on multiple devices

Comment: For a brief looking, your indeterminate result seems like a [concurrency issue](https://www.dlsweb.rmit.edu.au/Toolbox/knowmang/content/transmanagement/concurrency.htm). Your logic relies on reading a copy of balance in user beforehand. If multiple requests/devices access the same user object, you have no gurantee on which version of the balance read, which causes indeterministic result. Transaction is a common way to solve such an issue.

Comment: @ray thank you so much, i'll read about your link